# jsp open text file which is saved in folder : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/....txt

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am new to Jsp, I am using Spring MVC and trying to display a link when link click trying to open a text file from specific folder "href" is normally working in html page when I an trying to do the same in jsp getting error like this in console

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/....txt
```

### My jsp page looks like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="s"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: wheat;">
        <div align="center">
            <s:form commandName="salarySlipCommandName">
                <a href="D:\.....txt" target="_blank">click</a>
            </s:form>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to open text file from specified location, I have tried in multiple ways. can any one please suggest me in this regard..?